# Indexing matrix element member of struct

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I'm trying to index an element from a matrix, which has been declared by creating a vector of vectors inside a struct.
Here's my code:

```
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_DIM = 1000;

struct TestStruct{
    int MAX_DIM;
    vector<vector<int> > matrix (int MAX_DIM, vector<int>(int MAX_DIM));
};

int main(){
    TestStruct ts;
    ts.MAX_DIM = 100;
    ts.matriz[0][0] = 1;

    return 0;
}
```

While compiling I've recieved the following error:

```
test.cpp:14:17: error: invalid types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>[int]’ for array subscript
  mierda.matriz[0][0] = 1;
```

Btw, do you know any other "cleaner" way to declare the matrix (without using anything else than vector from the class Vector)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: s/matriz/matrix/

Comment: That doesn't declare a matrix, it declares a function.

Comment: How am I supossed to declare a matrix, then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code and your logic is that you think the line:

```
vector<vector<int> > matrix (int MAX_DIM, vector<int>(int MAX_DIM));
```

Creates a matrix inside your `struct`.

**In fact**, you just declared a function named `matrix` that returns a `vector<vector<int>`. To have a member object inside your `struct`, you need to delete the parentheses, as such:

```
vector<vector<int> > matrix;
```

I assume you want to first specify the `MAX_DIM` value and then create a matrix based on that value. I would either recommend creating a constructor that takes an `int` as argument to assign that value to `MAX_DIM` and then create a `matrix` based on that value, or to create an `initialise()` function that needs to be called before you access the `matrix`.

**First, preferable solution:**

```
using namespace std;
const int MAX_DIM = 1000;

struct TestStruct{
    TestStruct(int MD){
        MAX_DIM = MD;
        matrix = vector<vector<int>>(MD, vector<int>(MD));
    }

    int MAX_DIM;
    vector<vector<int>> matrix;

};

int main(){

    TestStruct ts(100); // matrix 100 by 100
    ts.matrix[0][0] = 1; // works

    return 0;
}
```

**Or, if you don't want to deal with constructors:**

```
using namespace std;
const int MAX_DIM = 1000;

struct TestStruct{

    int MAX_DIM;
    vector<vector<int>> matrix;

    void initialise(){
        matrix = vector<vector<int>>(MAX_DIM, vector<int>(MAX_DIM));
    }

};

int main(){

    TestStruct ts;
    ts.MAX_DIM = 100; // specify the size
    ts.initialise(); // construct the matrix
    ts.matrix[0][0] = 1; // works again

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the first solution requires less code and is more readable inside the `main` function. If you choose the second one, it will be easy to forget to either assign value to `MAX_DIM` or to call `initialise()`.